# Cannot dynamically set content with a new line in popup content of the bootstraps popover component

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I'm trying utilize bootstrap's popover component using my own custom string, but with a new line in it. I have researched this quite a bit and found a solution to getting new lines using the 'ng-template' tag, but this doesn't work for when trying to pass in a string with break's (br or \n).

I've tried many things using many combinations of innerHTML, strings within the dom, white-space: pre-line, json pipes. Nothing seems to work. The best I've gotten was [Object HtmlDivElement] when using innerHTML on a div instead of a ng-template. As said before the only way for this to work properly is to include hardcoded html within an ng-template then reference that ng-template in the 'ngbPopover' property. What is wrong with this is I don't have hardcoded HTML, but only a passed-in string (with HTML tags).

```
<ng-template #popContent style="white-space: pre-line;">{{controlModel.tooltip}}</ng-template>
            <div *ngIf="controlModel.tooltip" style="display:inline; white-space: pre-line;" [ngbPopover]="popContent"
                 popoverTitle="Tip" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"
                 placement="right"
                 container="body">
                <i class="icon-info"></i>
            </div>
```

The expected result is having new breaks included in the string 'controlModel.tooltip' show up in the popover contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by splitting the string of '\n' into a string array the doing the following:

```
<ng-template #popContent>
                <ng-container *ngFor="let splitString of tooltipSplit">
                    {{splitString}}<br />
                </ng-container>
            </ng-template>
```